# place the location marker in map?

Tags: google-maps-api-2

here I want to display the pin(marker) point location address for this latlng? And here I send one center also I have to sent two or more center(latlng) to API and get more marker location.

jQuery:

```
var map;
var geocoder;
var address;

function initialize() {
  map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(13.0423734,80.2727993), 10);
  map.setUIToDefault();
  geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="height:550px; width:950px">
  </div>
  </body>
```

where I include this code:

```
    map.setCenter(point, 13);
    var marker = new GMarker(point);
    map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Comment: My first suggestion is upgrading from a deprecated library to v3 if at all possible if you're not too deep into your Google Maps project yet. [Check out the v3 reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/).

Comment: I want to locate bubble for this latlng ..map.setCenter(new GLatLng(13.0423734,80.2727993), 10);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var map;
var geocoder;
var address;

function initialize() {
  map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(13.0423734,80.2727993), 10);
  map.setUIToDefault();
  geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
}


function showAddress(address) {
  geocoder.getLatLng(
    address,
    function(point) {
      if (!point) {
        alert(address + " not found");
      } else {
        map.setCenter(point, 13);
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

resource:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#Geocoding